# EF Migration errors

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

Getting error in EF migration with multiple applications in same project.  If we are adding a new application, previous error goes away and a new error shows up in the new application.

Comment: Do you mean EF (Entity Framework) migration?

Comment: yes. It is showing the object named 'XXX' is already in the database.

Comment: Yes. I have tried to enable, add migration and update database. Its is clearing error but if we are adding new application, showing error like "The object named "xxx" is already in the database" in the latest one

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of this other SO question: [I have three projects that share the same DB, whats the best way to use EF across all?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118775/i-have-three-projects-that-share-the-same-db-whats-the-best-way-to-use-ef-acros)

Comment: We have folder already which gives data access to all applications.